# Pandas - KeyError as column does not exist in the output

Tags: pandas, keyerror

I expect the final DataFrame to have the below structure:

```
col_a, col_b, col_c, col_d, col_e
```

However based on the data pulled from the API, I see the below columns having data

```
col_a, col_c, col_d
```

This results in a Keyerror as `col_b` and `col_e` are not in the data obtained from the API. Is there a way I can create empty columns if there is no data available based on the data obtained from the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by all expected columns names in list, if some column missing is added filled by default by missing values:

```
print (df)
   col_a  col_c  col_d
0      1      2      3

expected = ['col_a', 'col_b', 'col_c', 'col_d', 'col_e']
df = df.reindex(expected, axis=1)
print (df)
   col_a  col_b  col_c  col_d  col_e
0      1    NaN      2      3    NaN
```